# How to identify a computer in Java

Tags: java, sockets

I'm making a Cyber Café management software for a school project.

How can I identify each new computer (client) connected to the server?  I've done the connection already but I don't know how I can identify each computer.  I need to set a name or id to each client computer.

Can somebody give me example code or any suggestions? :)

```
ServerSocket server;
Socket client;

public void Sync() {
    try {
        server = new ServerSocket(35557);
        System.out.println("Server started, waiting for client...");
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Waiting for client...");
            client = server.accept();
            new Sync_procesador().start();
            System.out.println("Se conecto! :D");
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
    }

}
```

Comment: How do you *want* to identify them?

Comment: Google is your friend. If you looked at the ServerSocket API, you'd find that accept() returns a Socket, which has the method getInetAddress(), which returns the client's IP address.

Comment: @wohanley This should be answer ;)

Comment: Why do you want to identify the clients, what's your next step which would involve such an identifier?

Comment: @platzhirsch, Next i want to do is, List all computer connected on Socket (client-server), i want it to show on a Jpanel or label, i'm new on Java still,

Comment: @Takami I think displaying their IP address would be very suitable then.

Comment: Maybe if i make a new Thread on each client connected, so on Label i just add some text like "Computer: "+pcnumber... anyway i don't know very well how i will do this

Comment: @MadProgrammer I guess it didn't feel like enough effort, haha :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging from the comments, it seems to me that what you are really asking for is ideas on how to *display* the set of connected computers in a user interface.  (You already knew how to identify the computer.)

My suggestion is that you just try out some simple options and see if they work.  The basic idea is that you create a data structure that knows about all of the connected computers, and then you extract information (like a list of names) and display that in your UI.  It is up to you to decide what to display.  Possibilities include:

- the computer's IP address
- the computer's DNS name
- the name or nickname of the person using the computer (which you will need to get by getting the user to login or something)

I'd advise trying something simple and see how effective it is.  Then revise it (later on) if you have time in your project.

Answer (score 1):

you may want to get IP address of remote network card, just add

```
client.getInetAddress()
```

Comment: But where do i store the IP? i know how it this works but let's say that i want to list all computer into a jPanel with a label saying "Computer 1", computer "2","Computer"3",etc

Comment: I'd set up some kind of lookup that is keyed by the `InetAddress` class and contains the socket in mapped to it, say, something like a `Map<InetAddress, Socket>`. This would be maintained by something like a `ConnectionManager` singleton so you could access from anywhere in your code.

Answer (score 1):

The client is already identified through the socket object you receive on behalf of `server.accept()`. It really depends on what you want to do further with it. If you don't run applications using more than one port `socket.getInetAddress().getHostAddress()` should be just fine.

Comment: i know that :P but i want to list all computer conected on server into a jPanel by Adding Label(Icon) or some identifier, as i said it's like a Cyber Caffe managment software

Comment: @Takami How about a `List<String> clients`? Each time a new client connects, that is after the method `server.accept()` returns you retrieve the address and insert it into the list. Your GUI can then update on behalf of this list.